# Why am I segfaulting in this specific code?

Tags: c++

This program is supposed to take a file name and argument(s) and create a process that executes the code while outputting the result to the terminal (which I don't know why that isn't working either).

I have found that the seg fault is coming from my attempt to free the argvNew array of strings

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>


main(int argc, char **argv){
    int pid;
    int i;
    char *argvNew[argc-1];

    do{
        //Check for failure
        if ((pid = fork()) < 0) {
            cerr << "Fork error\n";
            exit(1);
        }
        //Check if parent
        else if (pid == 0) {
            /* child process */

            //Add arguments to new array
            for(i = 0; i < argc-2; i++){
                argvNew[i] = argv[i+1];
            }
            argvNew[argc-2] = NULL;

            if (execvp(argv[1], argvNew) < 0) {
                cerr << "Execve error\n";
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        else {
            /* parent */
            waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);/* wait for the child to finish */

            //Free argvNew 
            for(i = 0; i < argc-1;i++){
                free(argvNew[i]);
            }
            free(argvNew);
        }

        //if we're need to create a new list of args in the future put it here
    }while(!argc);
}
```

test input: `./myProgram /bin/ls -l`

Comment: There isn't a single `malloc`, `realloc`, `strdup`, etc. in your code for which to mate a `free()` call. In short, there is *no* dynamic allocation here whatsoever; only a non-C++-standard VLA. Thus you can assume *every* occurrence of `free` in this code is *wrong*.

Comment: Yea.. I'm starting to realize that I need to dynamically create an array of strings to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`argvNew` is *automaticlly allocated*, which means that the resources held by it are released automagiclly when it goes out of scope. You only need to `free` dynamicly allocated arrays:

```
char a[50]; // the [50] means automatic allocation
// ...
// no need to free
```

---

```
char* a = malloc(50); // dynamic allocation
// ...
// need to free later, or memory leak
free(a);
```

Comment: Square brackets don't necessarily indicate automatic allocation. In fact a declarator with identifier at block scope is automatic allocation, e.g. in your second example `a` itself is automatically allocated.

Comment: @M.M This is a simplified example to explain to someone how automatic allocation of arrays works in general, so while you are technicly correct, I don't belieive there is a need to edit that into the answer.

Comment: Hijacking this answer, I'm surprised that `char *arr[argc]` would even compile, I thought the value between brackets needed to be known at compile time, obviously it's not the case, what did I miss?

Comment: @vianney It's a VLA, or variable length array: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html

Answer (score -1):

```
for(i = 0; i < argc-1;i++){
    free(argvNew[i]);
}
//This next call is identical to free(argvNew[0]), probably where you're 
//segfaulting, since you're freeing something twice
free(argvNew);
```

Note that you don't need to call free(), since argvNew[] contains pointers that do not point to new/malloc'ed data, but rather to the values of the argv array, which are managed by the parent process and should not be explicitly free()'ed by you

Comment: `This next call is identical to free(argvNew[0])` - that is completely wrong. Those two things are *not* synonymous.

Comment: in fact it is identical to `free(&argvNew[0]);`